# Bash Script: Filter large files for value

Tags: bash, filter, grep

I have several config files with around 20k lines each and I need to get some values from them.
I know that each of the values I need starts with a specific word "CONFNET" so I tried to get the values with a while loop, which reads every line.

But unfortunately this is extremely inefficient and slow.

Is there a better solution to this?

```
for filename in ~/configs/*; do
    ip=$(cat $filename | strings | grep -i -A 7 "addnet_outside" | head -7 | grep "IP" | sed "s/IP//" | sed "s/=//" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')
    hostname=$(cat $filename | strings | grep -a "Inst:" | head -1 | sed "s/Inst://" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')





        while IFS= read -r line; do 
            object_name=$(echo $line | strings | grep "CONFNET" | sed "s/CONFNET//" | awk '{print $1}')
            object_value=$(echo $line | strings | grep "CONFNET" | sed "s/CONFNET//" | awk '{print $3}' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')
            if [ ! -z $object_name ]  && [ ! -z $object_value ]
             then
                echo $hostname "->" $object_name ":" $object_value


        done < "$filename"
done
```

Comment: If you could supply incoming and expected data people don't have to figure out what's going on. Also, using a lot of `|`s makes your script very slow. Did you know `sed` has extended regex in which you can use groups? Check `echo "==+DATA=aada" | sed -r 's/^[^\+]*\+([^=]*).*$/\1/'`. By using this, you can omit a lot of `grep`, `sed` and `awk` commands.

Comment: What is `strings`? grep and sed are as fast as you will get, if you let them do the work!

Comment: @GemTaylor `strings` extracts printable sequences from binary files. Not clear why config files wouldn't be text, though.

Comment: Yuk! That will slow things down. `grep -a`  will probably be faster?

Comment: Reading a file line by line and running grep, sed and awk on each line (twice!) is an antipattern. With that alone, you're invoking about 180,000 subprocesses for a 20K line file, when you could do everything with a single invocation of awk.

Comment: ...but as mentioned above, please provide sample input and expected output.

Comment: @Vengance : To add to the correct comments by BenjaminW: You are extracting in each line a substring. You can do this with just bash regular expressions - no need to create 13 child processes for each line being read!

Comment: The file is basically a backup file of a firewall.

There are tons of informations in it which I dont need and the only thing I know is that the section I'm looking for starts with the following block
```
CERTCHAIN = 
CLUSTER = EAS
```

And each of the parameters which I need starts with "CONFNET".
My goal is to get the object name (e.g. CONFNETCCL-APPLIANCES2[0]) and it's value (e.g. 1.1.1.1)


Example:
https://pastebin.com/t6U5cpe5